# eclipse xdebug session never completes

Tags: php, eclipse, xampp, xdebug

I am trying to get xdebug working with eclipse (3.5) / php (on xampp windows 7).  I have verified xdebug is enabled in php - I have the fancy output and my phpinfo shows all the xdebug stuff.  I have remote debug on, and typed in the lan ip address on my eclipse machine.

When I tell eclipse to debug, it launches the browser and passes the debug URL parameters.  That looks OK.

However, in eclipse debug perspective it shows 'launching myproject' 57%   'waiting for xdebug session'.   It sits there forever.

I have turned off windows firewall on both machines.

I tried turning implicit flush on.

Any ideas?

Comment: I feel a little stupid, but several hours later I figured out my problem was the comment `";"` at the beginning of this line: zend_extension="/blah/blah" I know is not an error or similar, but, maybe this can help.

Comment: One of the problems I was struggling with even after doing all these steps is highlighted in the following link..set xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388245/php-debug-configuration-hangs-waiting-for-xdebug-session-57

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I had this problem too and I was missing this line in the `php.ini` file:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = On
```

Comment: +1, I needed to do the same to get xdebug working with eclipse after installing xdebug on ubuntu using `apt-get install php5-xdebug`.

Comment: I also have this issue, it is stopped at 57% waiting for xdebug session, I've verified that xdebug.remote_enabled = On, and as per another discussion, i turned output buffering off.  it is still not working :(  I can't stand working without a debugger, it's painful.

Comment: If you have xdebug version 2.2.6 (or newer I assume) make sure you remove double quotes in xdebug.ini eg: xdebug.remote_host=localhost not xdebug.remote_host="localhost". Same with zend_extension, remote_handler and probably others

Comment: This line was not required for me in PHP 5.2 through PHP 5.4.. but when I upgraded to PHP 5.6 it broke, this answer fixed it!

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you defined zend_extention with **ABSOLUTE** path in the `php.ini`:

e.g.: `zend_extension=D:\SANDBOX\server\php\php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll`

I'm debugging a local project on Windows. So far I did not need `xdebug.remote_enable = On`.

Suggestions if the Xdebug session does not start (hangs at 57 %), make sure that:

- `zend_extention` directive is set with absolute path and the debug is loaded, use `phpinfo()` to check
- firewall does not block the default 9000 port or Eclipse.
- another application is not using the port (execute: `netstat -an |find /i "listening"` from the command line)

If you need to setup a different port use in `php.ini`:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_port = XXXX
```

and correct the Xdebug settings in Eclipse:

[image: XDEBUG settings in Eclipse]

Comment: "give me reputation and I can upload screenshots."  Upvoted you, but you could also post it to imgur and link.  I am in need of these images; can't figure out how to change the port.

Comment: Found it.  It's in Window->Preferences->PHP->Debug->InstalledDebuggers.  Something else was using port 9000.

Comment: Thank you so much. The example you have provided exactly fixed my problem.

Comment: I had a project that was not even a PHP project and aptana was often blocking port 9001. I went into Apatana > preferences and searched for debug, and under php it was certainly using port 9001. I changed this and haven't had a problem since. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by changing the port to XDebug (now using port 9001).

Here is my php.ini content:

```
zend_extension ="C:\...\EasyPHP-5.3.3\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
```

Also check the apache log file and make sure that you don't have the following Warning message:

PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0

**Warning**:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in **Unknown** on line **0**

If you do, open the php.ini file and comment with a ';' the `extension=php_xdebug-2.dll` line:

```
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_xsl.dll
**;extension=php_xdebug-2.dll**
;/PHPExt
```

Answer (score 7):

After fighting for 3 hours and trying out every solution on forums, I found out that the simple trick was to remove the quotes while specifying the **path of the Xdebug dll** in  **zend_extension** in **php.ini**. I am using XAMPP (PHP 5.3.6 + Apache 2.2)+ Eclipse Indigo + PDT + Xdebug 2.1.2 on Windows Vista.

Here is the exact configuration that worked for me -

```
zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc6.dll
#Note that the path above is not in quotes
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=C:\xampp\tmp
```

I have used port 9001 so that it does not clash with 9000 in case that's already used by another program. Make sure this matches the port in Eclipse > Preferences > PHP > Debug > Xdebug too. Also, restart apache after editing php.ini.

Once I added this to php.ini, everything worked like ice cream.

Comment: Same too, bloody damn qoutes and i was about to give up

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with Zend Studio. I have noticed that the xdebug session was not starting properly. I passed this string to the url once and it worked since then.

```
http://localhost/myalias/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=13750956767461
```

I'm sure it's a matter of configuration somewhere in the IDE.

Comment: I've been fighting this issue and trying everything I could find on a new dev environment setup. This simple post got it working for me. Litteraly a copy/paste from this post triggered a breakpoint. And from there simply hitting http://locahost worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me too. Can anyone explain what that weird "KEY" value is? The same value seems to work for everybody, which is strange...

Comment: And it also worked for me, when I set a breakpoint in Eclipse and enter this URL in the browser, without telling Eclipse to run or debug. So how do we configure PHP to do this? Mine was using `http://localhost/myalias/?XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP_NO_EXEC=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=14748086750741`

Comment: @pgr I found this page https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/16234/ which says `Is the "KEY=xxxx" argument really needed, and if so, how is it used?
The key is used to get around an issue with Internet Explorer where is caches
the page based on the URL. Eclipse would use IE as the internal web browser
and without using something that changed the URL you saw the same results being
displayed even though you had changed the script.`

Answer (score 3):

I realized that TCP port was in use and that was the reason why it was hanging. I changed port in php.ini and eclipse settings.

Comment: good tip.  another thing for people to consider - check if your firewall is the issue on the server - could be blocking the port when remote debugging

Comment: which settings in Eclipse ?

Comment: Under xdebug settings there is a port entry. That one. It needs to match the one in php.ini xdebug section. And it needs to be not in use. That was the core of my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check that Eclipse's web browser settings are correct.

Window/Preferences/General/Web Browser/external Web Browsers/Edit settings

In my case, the path to the external web browser binary was incorrect. It said "/usr/bin/mozilla" instead of "/usr/bin/firefox".
Don't know how this setting came about, but after changing it the firefox browser window came up at last.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into apache log and there were many lines with file not found error.

> Run -> Debug configurations -> PHP web page -> Your_configuration

I unchecked `auto generate` and set filename to `index.php`.

It seems that in case of any mistake that prevents eclipse from normal functioning causes this "waiting for session"

Comment: Upvote for suggesting looking at the Apache logs. This should be the first thing to check, even before looking at the Eclipse configuration (it didn't help me to solve my version of this problem, but it reminded me to be methodical)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. My configs were par with yours and in addition to having `xdebug.remote_enable = On` in the **php.ini** file also adding the following:

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

this enables multihost remote debugging, as an alternative you can define the host IP.

```
xdebug.remote_host=IP_ADDRESS
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, adding the **[xdebug]** configurations suggested by others to a php.ini file kept in following path C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin helped. Essentially it's a symbolic link that points/links to phpForApache.ini file under your respective php version folder that gets installed with wamp64 e.g. php5.6.25.

In nutshell, adding following lines ***phpForApache.ini*** to helped me -

```
    zend_extension = c:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.1-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll
    xdebug.remote_enable=On
    xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
    xdebug.remote_port=9000
    xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Xdebug 3 has changed the php.ini options (see https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide), and the default IP address has changed from 9000 to 9003.

As of PHP 8.2.6 and Xdebug 3.2.1 the following option enables xdebug:

```
xdebug.mode=debug
```

The port can be changed with:

```
xdebug.client_port=9010
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, check network/port stats.  In my case I'm using vmware fusion on mac, and the process vmware-natd was hogging the cpu (blocking on an open port I'm assuming), which I didn't notice.  php.ini was completely fine, had to run this to get it to work again:

```
sudo "/Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion/boot.sh" --restart
```

So ppl check your php.ini (or xdebug.ini) file first.  If it looks ok ala [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868568/xdebug-configuration-with-php-fastcgi-and-eclipse), then check that you're not having networking issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this means to you anymore or not! But, did you hit to a **PHP file** *(anything.php)* with right debug parameter, something like `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=12882809194391`.

**People often make mistakes to hit a HTML file with the debug parameters which causes Eclipse to hang at xdebug session**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turned out I was using the wrong dll. Hope that helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom. However, my problem was that I set 
    `xdebug.remote_host = ""`
I did this because I'm using apache virtual hosts to eliminate the need for `localhost`. However, I had change it back to 
    `xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"`
and then change my apache/etc/hpppd-vhosts.conf to have localhost point to my root c:\web.

Answer (score 0):

For me, these symptoms were caused by the windows firewall (Win7 Pro).  I needed to explicitly allow eclipse to pass the firewall.  I did this via the dialog at "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Firewall\Allowed Programs".

Answer (score 0):

It might not be useful to everybody, but... when trying to debug remote hosts, always remember the DSL router! (or any router along the way) I spent hours trying to find a solution, when I noticed that all I had to do was to activate port forwarding (port 9000) on my Linksys and everything worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

1. The above inputs were useful. I checked xdebug parameter values in phpInfo() and found that despite my settings to 1 or On, auto_trace and remote_enable were off. So i made it to **true**. And then remote worked!. Thanks.
2. Note, now you can launch the remote debugging session from within Eclipse by configuring various Debug configurations OR/and whenever you launch your such configured application outside Eclipse, you will get a question at Eclipse to accept or not to accept the debug session. So if you are on a different machine than of the eclipse UI you might find that the call to your application is getting timed out for no reason. Actually there would be a yes - no dialog box wherever the Eclipse session is

Answer (score 0):

If `Netweaver/Eclipse` fails to connect to `XDebug`, you may wish to check the `Apache` logs for occurrences of something like: `Cannot load Xdebug - it was built with configuration API220090626,TS,VC6, whereas running engine is API220090626,TS,VC9
[Fri Jun 01 18:38:05 2012] [notice] Child 3404: Child process is running`

To remedy this, pick the right version of the `XDebug` binary from the `XDebug` website (try a few combinations till you get it working)

Answer (score 0):

This thread helped me sort out my issue with MAMP on OSX with Eclipse. After upgrading to MAMP 2.1.1 from the 1.x release, I was not able to get xdebug to work in eclipse. It was hanging at the 57% level.

phpinfo showed that xdebug extension was loading fine and there were no errors in the PHP or Apache logs.

I only wanted to debug locally but the reason for the issue was that remote debugging was not enabled. Adding xdebug.remote_enable=true to the MAMP PHP.ini template and restarting MAMP solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case CLI application was working fine, but it was the web application which was getting stuck at 57%.

It worked after 2 changes:

1. made server debugger as XDebug
2. Auto Generate URL true.

Comment: how did you do these two steps?

Answer (score 0):

### Before eclipse setting, Check out the following content is visible in phpinfo function.

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered the same problem. I double checked all the settings in php with the output of `phpinfo()` and everything was fine.

### Allowing Java(TM) Platform SE binary through the firewall did the trick.

Check out the commands from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330523/step-by-step-how-to-do-xdebug-troubleshooting-connection-to-client-ide/27474600#27474600), they are very useful for debugging!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried every possible solution on this post to get xdebug to work on a site running on Apache (http port 8000) to no avail. I then accidentally  noticed that xdebug was working on another site that I had running on port 80. As soon as I changed the other site to port 80, it finally allowed me to debug it.

I wonder if there's a setting that can direct Apache to allow xdebug on other ports than just 80. I have more than one site running in Apache and would like to debug each of them without having to reconfigure the ports. Anyone had this issue before? or knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If your configuration is ok, just delete the file :
YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.root/.markers

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue using Uniserver Zero XIII 13.2.0 (requires MS VC12 redistributable install) and Eclipse Neon Release Candidate 3(4.6.ORC3). Our website uses phalcon, when we found an issue with the phalcon.dll and php7.0 we dropped back to php5.6. We verified xdebug settings above, added zend_extension=$(US_ROOTF)/php56/extensions/php_xdebug.dll--would not connect, no break points.

Found a warning at top of Eclipse Dialog Project | Properties |  PHP | Debug | Configure Workspace Settings... |  PHP Executables | PHP56(Workspace Default) | Edit | Debugger | "XDebug extension is not installed. Please visit http://xdebug.org...". This made us suspicious of the version of the php_xdebug.dll (2.5.0) in the Uniserver 13.2.0 php56. I downloaded php_xdebug-2.4.1-vc11.dll, dropped it in /php56/extensions and PRESTO! Eclipse PHP Debugger works!

Answer (score -1):

Here is another blog which mentions how to verify if Xdebug is properly installed or not via the command line
http://allcodeverything.blogspot.com/2012/07/code-debugging-with-xdebug-and-eclipse.html

It mentions this
If you want to figure out if everything worked well, here is a nice piece of code that you'll run through the CLI (command-line interpreter, basically outside of Apache or a browser; just pure PHP) after you have typed the following in your browser: "http://localhost/dbgtest.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ceable"

```
<?php
$address = "localhost";
$xdebug_port = 9000;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($sock, $address, $xdebug_port) or die('Unable to bind');
socket_listen($sock);
$debug_client = socket_accept($sock);
echo "connection established: $debug_client";
socket_close($debug_client);
socket_close($sock);
?>
```

The command-line window should print something like "connection established: Resource id #5".