# PHP debug configuration hangs - Waiting for XDebug session (57%)

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [eclipse xdebug session never completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374567/eclipse-xdebug-session-never-completes)

When I try to debug a php web page it hangs up. The message - waiting for XDEbug session. At the lower right corner there is another message - launching mydebugconf: (57%).

I am running XAMPP for Windows 1.7.7 with PHP 5.3.8 and Apache 2.0 on an x86 Windows 7 computer.

## phpinfo() - xdebug

```
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.idekey   DTWS01$ no value
xdebug.manual_url   www.php.net www.php.net
xdebug.max_nesting_level    100 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  C:\xampp\tmp    C:\xampp\tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name xdebug_profile.%R::%u   xdebug_profile.%R::%u
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  On  On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   c:\xdebug\log.txt   c:\xdebug\log.txt
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir C:\xampp\tmp    C:\xampp\tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth 3  3
```

==========================================================

## php.ini

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "xdebug_profile.%R::%u"
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_connect_back =1
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_log = "c:\xdebug\log.txt"
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

========================================

## netstat -a -b -n | find /i "listening"

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1025           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1026           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1027           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1029           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1030           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:9000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:10000          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:37674          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:53794          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:55723          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:60747          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:62062          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6880         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27015        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:45100        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.1.5:139        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:443               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:1025              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:1026              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:1027              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:1029              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:1030              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:3306              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:3389              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:5357              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:9000              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:10000             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:53794             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:55723             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:62062             [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

=================================================================

Thanks in advance for advice, suggestions or direction to other sources of relevant info.

DT

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to some server paths not having been set-up correctly in your IDE. You don't mention which IDE you're using so I can't help there.

Comment: I am using Eclipse. I can now get XDebug to work by setting xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0 - possibly because  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = ::1. This is consistent with @Derick answer. Now I need to figure out how to set-up the server paths. As you can see, I am doing this stuff for the first time.Thanks

Comment: Yeah, the ::1 won't work as Xdebug doesn't support IPv6 yet. And yes, setting connect_back to 0 makes it work then (as long as xdebug.remote_host is correct of course!)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem getting Xdebug working with Netbeans. Here's what I found. Hope it helps. [Xdebug + XAMPP + Netbeans = fail. Cannot get debugger to work in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193361/xdebug-xampp-netbeans-fail-cannot-get-debugger-to-work-in-netbeans)