# Xdebug + XAMPP + Netbeans = fail. Cannot get debugger to work in Netbeans

Tags: xampp, xdebug, netbeans-7

I've read other questions regarding this topic. The listed solutions haven't worked.

Installed:

> XAMPP 1.7.7
>
> Netbeans 7.1.1
>
> XDebug 2.1.4

phpinfo() shows that Xdebug is installed with all the correct parameters:

> zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.4-5.3-vc9.dll
>
> xdebug.remote_enable = on
>
> xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
>
> xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
>
> xdebug.remote_port = 9000

However, when I start a Netbeans debug session, it cycles for awhile with no effect. When I stop it, I get the Info box informing me that "No connection from xdebug was detected with in *nn* seconds. The reasons could be that **xdebug is not installed or not properly configured.** (their emphasis).

As far as I can tell, I configured everything correctly, restarted the Apache server and it still doesn't work. I'm at a total loss on how to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Create a debug log (see http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log) and see if xdebug tries to connect...

Comment: Tried adding this to php.ini: xdebug.remote_log = "c:/xampp/tmp/bp-edi.txt". Restarted apache, started debugger, ran for a few seconds, stopped it. No log file. :(

Comment: Verified that Xdebug is correctly installed via their test program. Changed log file location to xdebug.remote_log = "c:\xampp\apache\logs\xdebug_remote" based on another forum post. Still no output.

Comment: Another addendum: I ran php -m and received this response: [Zend Modules] Xdebug. So I know that php has the module loaded. I also learned that this issue is known by many as the dreaded "Waiting for Connection" spectre which has haunted more than just me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you believe it!? After spending literally HOURS researching this problem, I finally found the cause which I can only classify as a bug. Now, how do I report a bug? That's the next question.

Here's a summary:

> create PHP project and setup NetBeans project site root to subfolder.
>   (In order to not register for Apache new test site for any new task I
>   put every new task into subfolder under my local test domain, e.g.
>   http://test.my/project3/ ). NetBeans will not start debugging session
>   automatically in this case. You will see a ‘waiting for connection’
>   message from the image below. Do not worry. Left it as it is. Go to
>   your browser. I use FireFox 4. And call the script you wish to debug
>   with additional parameter, e.g.
>   http://test.my/project3/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
>
> When you return to NetBeans you will see that connection with xdebug
>   is established successfully. To stop XDebug session manually call any
>   script from the same subdirectory with this parameter
>   ?XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP_NO_EXEC=netbeans-xdebug

The complete solution can be found on my newest hero's blog [NetBeans 7.0 for PHP Waiting for Connection to XDebug](http://www.shinephp.com/netbeans-7-0-php-waiting-for-connection-to-xdebug/)

Edit: Know what I just discovered? I removed index.php as the index file of my run configuration. Works like a charm without having to manually insert the xdebug section of the url.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this with Netbeans 8 and while your answer worked around my problem I think I found the solution that will fix it forever.

Project Properties => Run Configuration => Advanced ... 
Ensure that  the following entry is selected
Debug URL: 'Default: YOUR URL'

Mine was set to "Do Not Open Web Browser" .....
Now it works as it used to work many months ago :)

Answer (score 1):

I am a .Net programmer and very new to PHP. Recently I was trying to host an open source PHP application on my machine(Windows). After the Struggle for 5-6 days I will list the steps which worked for me.

I uninstalled every previous installations of XAMPP and NetBeans and proceeded with fresh installations.

This might not be the solution for everyone but it worked for me and I hope it helps someone.

install XAMPP

install netbeans for PHP.

Open IIS and stop it. It is running on port 80 by default.(I am running XAMPP on port 80 i.e. default, Running on other port might need additional configuration settings)

Open XAMPP control panel and start Apache. If port 80 is free no problem should arise.

Open localhost in browser in should display XAMPP home page.

open phpinfo() link on the left pane and copy all the contents on page. Go to: http://xdebug.org/wizard.php and paste all the content in TextBox and click Analyze my phpinfo output. It will diplay you the Xdebug file suitable for your configuration.

Download the given Xdebug dll and copy it in C:\xampp\php\ext (Xampp being the default Xampp installation directory)

Goto XAMPP control panel, click on Config button in front of Apache and select php.in,

Find line similar or exacly like,

;zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"

(Semicolon means it is commented)

Remove the semicolon and replace the path with the path of dll you just copied like:

zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.2-5.4-vc9.dll"

Similarly find lines
;xdebug.remote_enable = 0 ;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"

remove semicolons in front of both lines and make remote_enable = 1

xdebug.remote_enable = 1 xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"

Restart Apache server.

Copy your website code under C:/XAMPP/htdocs/(your_website)/ that means your index.php should be at C:/XAMPP/htdocs/(your_website)/index.php

Open Netbeans select New project -> PHP -> PHP project from existing source and select the folder you just copied in htdocs folder. Set it to run on Local web server.

Set a breakpoint on first line of index.php and debug.

That's it.

Additional settings were suggested on various different posts but above mentioned steps worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be missing is

```
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
```

this is the settings I use in my php.ini

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1    # Not safe for production servers
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.remote_autostart=false
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Read the installation of XAMPP 1.7.7 & Netbeans 7.1 with edditing
   the php.ini file as suggested:
   http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-windows.html
2. Create your PHP project in the local XAMPP directory, `c:\xammp\htdocs\*yourproject*`
3. Debug the index.php, you will see that your browser will start with additional parameters:
   `http://*yourproject*/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug`
4. Go to your Netbeans, your debugger will be started.

Comment: I already resolved the question a month ago. Your answer added nothing new.