# Launching waiting for xdebug session 57%

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [eclipse xdebug session never completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374567/eclipse-xdebug-session-never-completes)

Problem:

In short, I am getting the "Launching waiting for xdebug session 57%" problem.

- I am running Eclipse Gallileo Build id: 20100218-1602 on Windows 7
  Ultimate
- I am running php 5.3.8
- The Zend Extension Build and PHP Extension Build are both - API220090626,TS,VC9

Solutions Tried:

I have verified that port 9000 is available for use, I have even tried other ports as a double check that ports was not the issue. That includes setting the ports in both the php.ini file and in the Eclipse development environment.

I have set the php.ini file as follows (I have also tried numerous other configurations - none worked):

zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php_xdebug-2.1.3-5.3-vc9.dll"

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

I am at a loss, can anyone help?

Comment: If you make a remote debugging log (http://xdebug.org/support.php#remote), what does it show?