# Symfony 3: Debugging with Symfony's development server

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu-16.04, xdebug, symfony-3.3

During the development on a Symfony 3.3 project I use the Symfony's internal server as seen [there](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html) But I cannot figure out how to use the xdebug in order to debug it. I mean I have installed and configured xdebug via:

```
apt-get install php-xdebug
```

And I export:

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=phpstorm"
```

But when I put a breakpoint to my IDE and I enable the xdebug via [that](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/the-easiest-xdebug/) plugin I still get no response.

Also I have put the following settings on `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini`

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_autostart=On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9021
xdebug.remote_mode=req
```

And I have configured both PhpStorm to listen over port 9021. But I still get the problem that I cannot make PhpStorm to listen over a breakpoint.

Do you fellows have any sort of idea how I can fix that over my ubuntu-16.04 machine?

Furthermore I have looked on these questions without any success:

- [Xdebug configuration with PHP fastcgi and eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868568/xdebug-configuration-with-php-fastcgi-and-eclipse)
- [Is it possible to use Xdebug with the built in PHP test server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496543/is-it-possible-to-use-xdebug-with-the-built-in-php-test-server#27520977)

## EDIT 1

I also tried to export the following:

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM"
```

An configuring the [Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/the-easiest-xdebug/) but still get the very same behaviour. Also keep in mind that I made the PhpStorm to listen over xdebug by pressing the [image: phpstop xdebug button] button.

## EDIT 2

I also put the following configuration over my PhpStorm:

[image: Php configuration]

Still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end the following steps are needed:

1. Put the following content into: `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini`

   ```
   zend_extension=xdebug.so
   xdebug.remote_enable=On
   xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
   xdebug.remote_host=localhost
   xdebug.remote_port=9021
   xdebug.remote_mode=req
   ```
2. Export:

   ```
   export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM"
   ```
3. Then configure PhpStorm as the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N72hh.png) shows.
4. Set as IDE key `PHPSTORM`  into the [Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/the-easiest-xdebug/)
5. Enable xdebug on Firefox via pressing the [image: Firefox enable xdebug button] button. Alternatively you can append the url with `?XDEBUG_START` part
6. Then press the [image: button disabled xdebug] button in PhpStorm. In case you see the [image: PhpStorm enable xdebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whuPx.png) button press that until it becomes ![button disabled xdebug] then press it back again.

**NOTE:**

In case you change xdebug settings **TERMINATE** the xdebug session by pressing [image: PhpStorm enable xdebug] button and pressing back again.

Furthermore in case you run composer via terminal **disable** PhpStorm to listen xdebug by pressing [image: PhpStorm enable xdebug] button.

Comment: *"Then configure PhpStorm as the image shows"* You are NOT using DBGp Proxy -- please do not confuse people with useless stuff (just because it has possibly-related-at-first-glance fields). 1) Are you actually using DBGp Proxy? 2) Have you actually installed that software (which is a completely separate thing)? 3) Do you use `DBGp Proxy | Register IDE` in order to actually use it?  I'm sure it will be "No" for all 3 of them .. as this is simply not needed for local development.

Comment: *"Enable xdebug on Firefox via pressing the Firefox enable xdebug button button. Alternatively you can append the url with ?XDEBUG_START part"* If you are using `xdebug.remote_autostart=On` then Firefox addon is simply not needed at all .. as with that option xdebug will try to debug **every single script** (so you will see approx 1 sec delay when each script executes while it tries to connect to debug client). Better turn it off and initiate sessions via that addon (or query string parameter).

Comment: LazyOne pleasem look on `xdebug.ini` over `xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp`

Comment: And?.. It's a standard thing -- default handler. It has no relation to DBGp Proxy if that's what you are referring to. Have a read on what DBGP Proxy is used for: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Multi-user+debugging+in+PhpStorm+with+Xdebug+and+DBGp+proxy